# I have installed Auditbeat today and want to view audit logs which are older than a month. Is this achievable somehow?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed Auditbeat today and want to view audit logs which are older than a month in Elasticsearch. Is this achievable somehow?

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

`Auditbeat` is a data shipper so it is just going to move the data around.

This data is mainly event, and `Auditbeat` listen to then, it is not reading them from a file so sadly I don't think so.

## To understand

`Auditbeat` is [composed of 3 modules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/auditbeat-modules.html):

#### [AuditD](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/auditbeat-module-auditd.html)

Get event from the kernel as the come.

> This module establishes a subscription to the kernel to receive the events as they occur.

So no way to get the data from earlier this month.

#### [File integrity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/auditbeat-module-file_integrity.html)

> This module uses features of the operating system to monitor file changes in realtime.

It will not be able to get events from a month back.

#### [system](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/auditbeat-module-system.html)

> Event information is sent as the events occur (e.g. a process starts or stops).

Yet again, not possible.

So you won't be able to access the data from a month from now.